# Good way to determine max characters to allow in user generated area on a web page

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, user-generated-content

I'm working on a coupon app and it has an area where business owners can enter a short "tag line" for what the coupon is for. For example:

- 10% off one entree!
- $5 off
- 2 for 1 sake before 7PM
- 15 free flapjacks if your name is Gary

Again, this is user generated. It will show up on a screen their customers can see. I'd like it to display on one line within a certain amount of pixels. It will be in Arial.

**What is the best way to determine the max amount of characters to allow them to include so that it doesn't take up extra lines or overflow, considering lots of browsers...?**

Comment: i tried using w, and then entering a few common "tag lines" customers might use and get for ex. max 11 char with w, and avg 14-17 with typical phrases... anyone have any experience with this? anyone used fittext jquery or similar?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `font`, `font-size`, and total `width` of the one line then you could just do a trial and error calculation (that is, enter characters until the end of the line).

Once you know that, you can check for the total # of characters on `keyup` and alert if that amount is reached.

For instance, as an example only, let's say you choose Arial 14px and you've tested it to see that 10 characters is *about* all that one line can hold.  Then you can add something like this

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length == 10){
        alert('You\'ve reached the limit');
    }
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uGDKn/

Comment: What do you mean use "w"?  Sorry, I'm not sure about that.  Fyi, see my edit above.

Comment: Ok, I get it now.  Use w as the biggest letter to ensure that you get the best length result.  Yes, do that.

Comment: Yes @Andypandy.  I just figured that out!! ;-)  Agreed.  Use w's as a good measure for the length.  Fyi... no experience with fittext.js